# order by to the linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How to add orderby function in this linq query.I want to display the rows orderby the calculated vote(You can see the calculation inside select query)

```
(from e in db.FoodItems
                  join o in db.Ratings
                       on e.itemid equals o.itemid into g



           select new FoodView
              {   itemid=e.itemid,
                  caption=e.caption,
                  description=e.description,
                  price=e.price,
                  pubdate=e.pubdate,
                  imageurl=e.imageurl,
                  videourl=e.videourl,
                  itemname = e.itemname,
                  vote = (long)Math.Round((double)(g.Sum(x => (int?)x.vote) ?? 0) / g.Count(),0)


              }).Take(8).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.OrderBy(x => x.vote).Take(8).ToList()
```

Comment: @user3300195, the one came from the FoodView entity created on the previous step. Thus the calculated one.

Comment: Do you want the top 8 highest votes? Or the top 8 lowest votes?

Comment: Is there any way to give condition for g.Count() to divide only it is greater than 1?

Comment: Is there any way to give condition for g.Count() to divide only it is greater than 1?

Comment: @user3300195, you can do something like (g.Count() > 1 ? g.Count() : 1), although this might call `Count` twice

Comment: @Andrei:I got that solution using (g.Count() > 1 ? g.Count() : 1).Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you just add it after the take?

```
(from e in db.FoodItems
 join o in db.Ratings
         on e.itemid equals o.itemid into g
 select new FoodView
          {   itemid=e.itemid,
              caption=e.caption,
              description=e.description,
              price=e.price,
              pubdate=e.pubdate,
              imageurl=e.imageurl,
              videourl=e.videourl,
              itemname = e.itemname,
              vote = (long)Math.Round((double)(g.Sum(x => (int?)x.vote) ?? 0) / g.Count(),0)
          }).OrderBy(f => f.vote).Take(8).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have...

```
.Take(8).ToList().OrderBy(item => item.vote);
```

Comment: ok, I was too late :P Some other people already answered the same, sorry!

Comment: No problem.I have enough questions.